# strpos() returning false, when needle is in haystack

Tags: php, strpos

I was having trouble with a longer func i wrote, so i broke it down and it seems to be with the `strpos()` function.

Even though the needle is clearly present in the haystack it returns false, for the life of me i cant work out why, oddly though if i change the needle to "sam" in becomes true.. any idea why ?

```
function verify_url($url) {
    if (strpos($url, "http://")) {
        return $url;
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}


$url = "http://sam.com";

echo verify_url($url);
```

Comment: You should use `===` instead of `==` at any time, except very very rare cases. `===` performs better than `==` and it never gives confusing conversion like `==`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is returning 0, not false. In the `if` test PHP evaluates integer value 0 as boolean value false.

Use `strpos($url, "http://") !== false` to check both value and data type. It is called strict comparison.

Manual: [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Answer (score 3):

Replace your `if (strpos($url, "http://"))` with below one.

```
if (strpos($url, "http://") !== false)
```

It's giving `0` (and not `false`) because it found `http://` at `0th` position